# How to specify the response_model in FastAPI on a non-default return?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have the following route:

```
# 201 is the response from a creation
# 409 if it already exists
# The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.
@app.post("/users", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=schemas.UserResponse)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    # hash the password -- user.password
    user.password = utils.hash(user.password)
    new_user = models.User(**user.dict()) # get or create? -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6078058/651174
    db.add(new_user)
    try:
        db.commit()
    except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
        db.rollback()
        existing_user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == user.email).first()
        raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail=existing_user)

    db.refresh(new_user) # the same as doing `RETURNING *`
    return new_user
```

The `user` object returns and is encoded fine when it doesn't hit the exception. However, when it does go through the exception, and executes:

```
raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail=existing_user)
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable

Is there a way to basically encode all responses using the model I specify in FastAPI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that your `new_user` object is returned successfully when the request doesn't hit the exception is that (as explained in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#return-a-response-directly)):

> By default, FastAPI would **automatically** convert that return value to
> `JSON` using the `jsonable_encoder` explained in [JSON Compatible
> Encoder](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/). Then, behind the scenes, it would put that
> JSON-compatible data (e.g. a `dict`) inside of a `JSONResponse` that
> would be used to send the response to the client.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) in more detail,  when returning a value from an endpoint, FastAPI will first convert the value into JSON-compatible data using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/), thus ensuring that any objects that are not serializable, such as `datetime` objects, are converted to a `str`. Hence, avoiding any potential errors, such as:

```
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

when FastAPI will later put that data into a `JSONResponse`, which uses the standard `json.dumps()` function to convert the data into JSON (see the linked answer above for more details and references).

However, when raising an [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-httpexception), which would actually return a `JSONResponse` directly without using the `jsonable_encoder` first to ensure that the data are JSON-compatible (you can check that through [`http_exception_handler`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/5c576e42be8f8832f0e225beaa72153a256892d7/fastapi/exception_handlers.py#L9)), you would need to convert the `existing_user` object/model using `jsonable_encoder` by yourself, before passing it to the exception. As described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#using-the-jsonable_encoder-in-a-response):

> You cannot put a Pydantic model in a `JSONResponse` without first
> converting it to a `dict` with all the data types (like `datetime`,
> `UUID`, etc) converted to **JSON-compatible** types.

Hence, you should use:

```py
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

raise HTTPException(detail=jsonable_encoder(existing_user), status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```