# Pass multiple JSONResponse in fastapi endpoint

Tags: python, api, http, fastapi, endpoint

Good night guys, I have a question, I have a function on an endpoint using fastapi, when I make the request, it executes and returns me return `JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"result": 'result'})` . Ok so far, but I want to pass more than one of this JSONResponse.

My idea would be to pass several to test JSONResponse, to be able to create tests and test my apis

```py
JSONResponse(status_code=500, content={"Erro": result})

JSONResponse(status_code=422, content={"Erro": result})

JSONResponse(status_code=404, content={"Erro": result})
```

I even made an endpoint, to do a little test, if I have the error return. But it keeps giving status code 200
I see that I batched JSONResponse, in the code. But it was to try to find where the return problem was.

```py
@application.post("/division")
def calculator_division(item_to_calculator: Item_to_calculator):
    try:
        json_item = jsonable_encoder(item_to_calculator)
        result =  json_item['first_item'] / json_item['second_item']        
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stdout.write(f'Exception: {e}')  
        return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content={"Error":'Error'})     
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"result": result})
```

Return in terminal:

```bash
services-calculator_api-1  | Exception: float division by zeroINFO:     172.23.0.3:60058 - "POST /division HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
services-calculator_api-1  | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
services-calculator_api-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
services-calculator_api-1  |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 271, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 118, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     raise exc
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     raise exc
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     raise e
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
services-calculator_api-1  |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
services-calculator_api-1  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
services-calculator_api-1  |     response = await func(request)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
services-calculator_api-1  |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in run_endpoint_function
services-calculator_api-1  |     return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
services-calculator_api-1  |     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
services-calculator_api-1  |     return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
services-calculator_api-1  |     return await future
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
services-calculator_api-1  |     result = context.run(func, *args)
services-calculator_api-1  |   File "/apis/./app/main.py", line 58, in calculator_division
services-calculator_api-1  |     return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"result": result})
services-calculator_api-1  | UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

I want to know another way to pass several different status_code responses so I can test the endpoint calls. Because the exception is not working very well. Thank you for your attention. Good night.

I want to know another way to pass several different status_code responses so I can test the endpoint calls. Because the exception is not working very well. Thank you for your attention. Good night.

Comment: The link above, among other things, demonstrates how to raise an `HTTPException`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140957/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73161870/17865804) as well.

Comment: @Chris  , good afternoon. Thanks for the help I looked at the links you sent. The best option was to use Depends. The treatment turned out much better than I imagined. HTTPException, successfully caught.