# How to return Pydantic model using Field aliases instead of names in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, alias, pydantic

My FastAPI call is not returning the data in correct `Response` model format. It is returning data in database model format.

My database model:

```py
class cat(DBConnect.Base):
     __tablename__ = 'category'
     __table_args__ = {"schema": SCHEMA}
     cat_id = Column('cat_id',UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
     cat_desc = Column('cat_desc', TEXT, nullable=True)
     cat_h__l_name = Column('cat_h_l_name', TEXT, nullable=True)
```

My Pydantic Model:

```py
class CamelModel(BaseModel):
    class config:
        alias_generator = to_camel
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

class cat(CamelModel):
    cat_id =Field(alais='CatID', readonly=True)
    cat_description =Field(alias='CatDescription')
    cat_h__l_name = Field(alias='CatName')
     
    class config:
       orm_mode= True
```

My API CAll:

```py
@router.patch('/cat/{id}/', response_model = 'cat')
def update_cat(response= Response, params: updatecat = Depends(updatecat)):
    response_obj = { resonse_code: status.HTTP_200_OK, 
    response_obj : {}    
    }
    
    response_obj = session.query() # It is returning the correct data from the database
    response.status_code = response_obj['response_code']
    
    return JSONResponse(response_obj['response_obj'], status_code = response_obj['response_code'])
```

Getting Response in below format:

```
     cat_id = 'some uuid'
     cat_desc = 'desc'
     cat_h__l_name = 'some h_l_name'
```

but I want the response to be in the below format:

```
CatID = 'some uuid'
CatDescription ='' some description'
CatName = 'Some cat name'
```

This code is not giving any errors (I have typed it, so might be some indentation or spelling mistake). The only issue is that the API doesn't return data in correct format. I have been stuck on it for a while. I am new to FastAPI. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

To return a Pydantic model from an API endpoint using the `Field` aliases instead of names, you could add `response_model_by_alias=True` to the endpoint's decorator. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/?h=response_model_by_alias#response_model_include-and-response_model_exclude). Using `response_model_by_alias=False` would have the opposite effect. The example below uses the Model's Config [`alias_generator`](https://%20https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/model_config/#alias-generator) to automatically generate aliases for the fields.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


def to_pascal(string: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(word.capitalize() for word in string.split('_'))

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    language_code: str
    
    class Config:
        alias_generator = to_pascal
        allow_population_by_field_name = True    
            

fake_db = [
    Item(Name='foo', LanguageCode='en'),
    Item(Name='bar', LanguageCode='fr')
]


@app.get('/item/{item_id}', response_model=Item, response_model_by_alias=True)
def create_item(item_id: int):
    return fake_db[item_id]
```

In **Pydantic V2**, you could use the `alias_generator` in a `ConfigDict` class, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.alias_generator). Pydantic offers three **built-in** alias generators: `to_pascal`, `to_camel`, and `to_snake`. Also, in v2.0, the `allow_population_by_field_name` configuration setting was changed to [`populate_by_name`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.populate_by_name). This setting indicates whether an aliased field may be populated by its *name* as given by the model attribute, as well as the *alias*. Defaults to `False`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
from pydantic.alias_generators import to_pascal

class Item(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(alias_generator=to_pascal, populate_by_name=True)
    name: str
    language_code: str
```

If one would like to create a `Field` alias without using an `alias_generator`, they could achieve this as follows:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, Field

class Item(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)
    name: str = Field(..., alias='Name')
    language_code: str = Field(..., alias='LanguageCode')
```

In case you used an `alias_generator`, as well as specified an `alias` on the `Field`, the `alias` will take [precedence over the generated alias](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/alias/#alias-precedence) by default.

Also, as explained in Pydantic's [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/#field-aliases):

> The `alias` parameter is used for **both** *validation* and
> *serialization*. If you want to use different aliases for *validation* and *serialization* respectively, you can use the `validation_alias`
> and `serialization_alias` parameters, which will apply only in their
> respective use cases.
>
> In case you use `alias` together with `validation_alias` or
> `serialization_alias` at the same time, the `validation_alias` will
> have priority over `alias` for validation, and `serialization_alias`
> will have priority over `alias` for serialization.
>
> You may also set [`alias_priority`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/alias/#alias-priority) on a field to change this behavior.

### Returning a Pydantic model using `JSONResponse`

It should also be noted that you seem to be returning a [`JSONResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#jsonresponse) instead of a Pydantic model from your API endpoint; hence, setting `response_model_by_alias=True` wouldn't have any effect. Thus, you could convert the model to a dictionary, using Pydantic's `model.dict(...)` (**Note** that, in Pydantic V2, this method has been replaced by [`model.model_dump(...)`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump)), and set the `by_alias` argument to `True`.

On a side note, [you cannot put a Pydantic model in a `JSONResponse` without first converting it to a `dict`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#using-the-jsonable_encoder-in-a-response), if  you have data types, such as `datetime`, `UUID`, etc., that cannot be serialised. For those cases, you can use the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/) to convert your data before passing it to a response. The `jsonable_encoder` will ensure that objects that are not serializable will be converted to a `str`.

```py
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

@app.get('/item/{item_id}')
def create_item(item_id: int):
    return JSONResponse(jsonable_encoder(fake_db[item_id].model_dump(by_alias=True)), status_code=200)
```