# Validation errors on output model when input model is populated by alias

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Given an input model with a field `alias`, and a output model without, shouldn't FastAPI still be able to implicitly [convert the output data](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model) according to `response_model`? In the example below, a validation error is being raised. What am I doing wrong?

```py
1 validation error for OutModel
response -> foo
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

```py
import fastapi
import starlette.testclient
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

class DbModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str = Field(alias='bar')

class OutModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str

@app.get('/test', response_model=OutModel)
def test():
    foo = DbModel(bar="foo")
    print(foo.dict()) # {'foo': 'foo'}
    return foo


with starlette.testclient.TestClient(app) as test_client:
    try:
        print(test_client.get('/test').json())
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return Pydantic model using Field aliases instead of names in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74332593/how-to-return-pydantic-model-using-field-aliases-instead-of-names-in-fastapi)

Answer (score 0):

response_model accept dictionary or orm class instance when config has orm=True.

I think you need to fix like below,

```
@app.get('/test', response_model=OutModel)
def test():
    foo = DbModel(bar="foo")
    return foo.dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is why that problem arises.

When receiving a Pydantic `BaseModel` instance from the route handler function, FastAPI actually passes `by_alias=True` to `BaseModel.dict` before serializing the result and returning it in the form of a response. ([source](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.88.0/fastapi/routing.py#L77))

In your case, this results in the output `{'bar': '...'}`. Validation via your defined `response_model` is done with this data. And since `OutModel` does not have the `bar` alias defined for its `foo` field, it simply detects that `foo` is missing.

I am not exactly sure, why it is done this way or what the trade-offs were, but I suspect it is because you would typically assume that the alias was defined for a reason and thus should be preferred.

---

The first workaround is what @rumbarum already mentioned, namely generating and returning the dictionary yourself *without* setting `by_alias=True` (it is `False` by default). This would give the response model the data it expects.

The other option I found was to set `read_with_orm_mode = True` on the `DbModel.Config` class. However, I think this is not a documented config parameter. I did not find any mention of it in the Pydantic docs or in the FastAPI docs. Just as a side note in the [changelog](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/?h=read_with_orm#0681). For this reason, I would regard it as a current implementation detail and use it with caution.

The idea here seems to be to allow `BaseModel.from_orm` to generate the desired response model instance. And that process simply picks the attributes it needs by the field name.

Here is a working example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from starlette.testclient import TestClient


app = FastAPI()


class DbModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str = Field(alias='bar')

    class Config:
        read_with_orm_mode = True


class OutModel(BaseModel):
    foo: str


@app.get('/test', response_model=OutModel, response_model_by_alias=False)
def test():
    foo = DbModel(bar="foo")
    return foo


with TestClient(app) as test_client:
    try:
        print(test_client.get('/test').json())
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```