# Alias in fastapi with jsonable encoder

Tags: fastapi, alias

I want to change my field names in POST and GET router of fast api

I want to change username to Name in request
I have done following code

```py
 class User(BaseModel):
    
    username : str
    password : str
    
    @validator('username','password')
    def clean_space(cls, v):
        if  v=="" or v==None or v=="None":
            raise ValueError('This field is required')
        return v
    
    class Config():
        orm_mode =True
   
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                 'username' : "",
                 'password' : "", 
            }
        }

@router.get('/user',tags=['user'])
def get(request: Request,user_id:Union[int,None]=None,db:Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
    try:
        Q = db.query(user)
        records = Q.all()
        if records:
           result =  jsonable_encoder(records)
           message = 'User Details fetch successfully.'
        else:
            message = 'User Details not found.'
            data = {'status':'success','error_code': 0, 'method': request.method, 'message': message, 'data':result, 'total_count': total_records, 'from_date': from_date, 'to_date': to_date}
            return JSONResponse(data)
```

It displays username and encrypted password but instead of username I want Name as alias

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return Pydantic model using Field aliases instead of names in FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74332593/how-to-return-pydantic-model-using-field-aliases-instead-of-names-in-fastapi)