# How to return Pydantic object with a specific http response code in FastAPI?

Tags: python, http, fastapi, pydantic

I have an endpoint which returns a Pydantic object. However, I would like a response code other than 200 in some cases (for example if my service in not healthy). How can I achieve that with FastAPI?

```
class ServiceHealth(BaseModel):
    http_ok: bool = True
    database_ok: bool = False

    def is_everything_ok(self) -> bool:
        return self.http_ok and self.database_ok

@router.get("/health")
def health() -> ServiceHealth:
    return ServiceHealth()
```

Comment: Did you check https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#fastapis-httpexception-vs-starlettes-httpexception ?
Something like: raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Service not found.") can be useful for your intent ?

Comment: Hum, I still would like to return a Pydantic object.

Comment: Future readers might want to have a look at the last section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333692/17865804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a [Response Directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/).

For example, you can use `JSONResponse` and set the `status` manually:

```
@router.get("/health")
async def health() -> ServiceHealth:
    response = ServiceHealth()
    
    if response.is_everything_ok():
        return JSONResponse(content=response.dict(), status_code=200)
    return JSONResponse(content=response.dict(), status_code=500)
```

Also, there is a handy `status.py` which you can import from `fastapi` that contains all the available status codes:

```
from fastapi import status

@router.get("/health")
async def health() -> ServiceHealth:
    response = ServiceHealth()
    
    if response.is_everything_ok():
        return JSONResponse(content=response.dict(), status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return JSONResponse(content=response.dict(), status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: When returning a `JSONResponse(content=some_dict, ....)`, please make sure that all objects in the dictionary that is being returned are JSON-serializable objects, otherwise a `TypeError: Object of type ... is not JSON serializable` would be raised. In that case, one should either convert such objects to a type that is JSON-serializable (e.g., `str`) on their own, or use FastAPI's `jsonable_encoder()` function that would automatically do this (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details and examples).

Comment: @Chris Yes, that is correct! Another thing you can do when you have a Pydantic object (with `datetimes` for example, that are not JSON serializable) in order to make sure they will be serialized correctly is to use the following combo: `json.load(pydantic_instance.json())`

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Please have a look at the linked answer above, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804) (see Option 1) to find out the reason as to why. Simply, you are converting the model instance into JSON, then the JSON string/object into dictionary, and finally, once again into JSON, since `JSONResponse` will use `json.dumps()` behind the scenes (as explained in the links provided above).

Comment: You could instead use: `return Response(model.json(), media_type='application/json', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`. See the linked answers above for more details.

Comment: as a side note,`status` is now `status_code` for 0.104.1

Comment: @Bennimi good catch, I have updated the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the [`status_code`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.0/fastapi/routing.py#L329) keyword-argument, when initializing your `APIRoute`. It is passed along by all route decorators as far as I know, including [`APIRouter.get`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.0/fastapi/routing.py#L834).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ServiceHealth(BaseModel):
    http_ok: bool = True
    database_ok: bool = False


api = FastAPI()


@api.get("/health", status_code=299)
def health() -> ServiceHealth:
    return ServiceHealth()
```

Performing a `GET` on that route still returns the expected JSON `{"http_ok":true,"database_ok":false}` with the HTTP status code 299 (just to demonstrate, not a "real" status code).

There are a few restrictions that FastAPI places on that argument. Notably, you cannot return a body, if you define a [`304`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) status code or any informational (`1xx`) status code.